# how to increase the threads in JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, alfresco

I am working alfresco server. It is build on top of Tomcat.

I had written the following code the the server.xml file

I increased the database max.connection pool setting to  300.

But the Jconsole is showing the

live threades: 120
peek threads : 141

why this is happening?
 i am given max threads as 290. how can i increasethe peek threads value

Thanks & regards,
murali.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `server.xml` for the Connector element it has an attribute maxThreads, you might want to increase it.

```
  <Connector port="8080" maxThreads="500" .... />
```

Thats bevause the number of threads limits the number sessions you can have in a web application.